# Matlab coneplot meshgrid error MATLAB:griddedInterpolant:NdgridNotMeshgrid3DErrId / not plotting anythin

Tags: matlab, plot, runtime-error

Basically I want to plot a 3D vector field using coneplot in Matlab.
My script looks like this:

```
data=oommf2matlab('420x350x5-2_5-5.omf');
x=linspace(data.xmin,data.xmax,data.xnodes);
y=linspace(data.ymin,data.ymax,data.ynodes);
z=linspace(data.zmin,data.zmax,data.znodes);
[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(y,x,z);
scale=4;
angle = data.datay ./ data.datax;
colors = angle;
figure;
coneplot(data.positionx,data.positiony,data.positionz,data.datax,data.datay,data.dataz,X,Y,Z,scale,colors);
```

[oommf2matlab](http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44187-oommf-vector-data-file-to-matlab-array/content/oommf2matlab.m) is a function for converting my data into matlab and returns a structure like this:

```
xmin: 0
ymin: 0
zmin: 0
xmax: 4.2400e-07
ymax: 3.5400e-07
zmax: 1.2500e-08
xnodes: 212
ynodes: 177
znodes: 5
datax: [212x177x5 double]
datay: [212x177x5 double]
dataz: [212x177x5 double]
positionx: [212x177x5 double]
positiony: [212x177x5 double]
positionz: [212x177x5 double]
```

Running this script gives me an error

> Error using interp3 (line 146) Input grid is not a valid MESHGRID.
>
> Error in coneplot (line 144)    ui = interp3(x,y,z,u,cx,cy,cz,method);
>
> Error in omf2cone (line 11)
>   coneplot(data.positionx,data.positiony,data.positionz,data.datax,data.datay,data.dataz,X,Y,Z,scale,colors);

If traced the error via debugging to the MATLAB:griddedInterpolant:NdgridNotMeshgrid3DErrId error which looks like this:

```
identifier: 
'MATLAB:griddedInterpolant:NdgridNotMeshgrid3DErrId'

message: 
Data is in MESHGRID format, NDGRID format is required.
Convert your data as follows:
P = [2 1 3];
X = permute(X, P);
Y = permute(Y, P);
Z = permute(Z, P);
V = permute(V, P);
F = griddedInterpolant(X,Y,Z,V)
cause: {0x1 cell}
stack: [3x1 struct]
```

This is strange to me, because interp3 already does what the error suggests as a fix.

Also if I let coneplot generate the mesh itself via:

```
coneplot(data.datax,data.datay,data.dataz,X,Y,Z,scale,colors);
```

There is no error, however there is no plot created whatsoever, only the axis of the figure.

Comment: could the error be in this line `[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(y,x,z);` where instead you want `[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(x,y,z);`?

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `meshgrid` use `griddedInterpolant()` instead so that your data is in the format identified in the error.

Also part of your error could be in this line `[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(y,x,z);` where instead you want `[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(x,y,z);`? This could cause the syntax error you are describing

Comment: Can you elaborate why and how to use griddedInterpolant() here, please. Matlab documentation on coneplot suggests using meshgrid.

Also this permutation was intentional to get the same array dimensions.
[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(x,y,z) gives 177x212x5 arrays for X,Y,Z
while the data is obviously in 212x177x5.

Comment: using the griddedInterpolant class (using functions like interp3), interpolates the mesh grid data that you have provided so that it becomes equally spaced and is then in a consistent format with constant spacing, which matlab prefers for some plots. there is more information at [mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/interpolating-gridded-data.html). Does that answer your question?